# Blender exporting wrong image

Tags: texturing, export

I created an object and initially mapped the wrong texture to it. Now, even after loading, applying & UV Mapping the correct texture, every time I export my model, it still exports the old/wrong texture instead.

I even tried "packing" the new texture, but it didn't help.

I'm a bit of a Blender novice, and I still use old v2.79b because I never learned the new version/interface.

Why is Blender still exporting my model with the wrong texture? How do I fix this?

TIA

(I've attached the source files [here](https://mega.nz/file/aQUHCaQS#l4FEhDdRGvEPMKgWQ9Dg2eJcDE9kQaksrmXlxbaue_w) if anyone wants to test it.)

Comment: I dont think we can help without seeing yor blend https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Because it is JPEG file :) You or someone accidentally changed file type to PNG just in name. Export fixed the issue :) If you check metadata you can see. I also see you used Photoshop ... so you can check File > File Info ... sorry for late info ... for quicker response its better to type me a comment as @vklidu